# modifying the default compiler path for building boost

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I have an old version of boost 1.33.1. I want to build it with a custom gcc binary whih is in a path other than default. I could not find the page on the web so I paste the first part of the `gcc-tools.jam` form `tools/build/v1/gcc-tools.jam`.

## Copyright (c) 2001 David Abrahams.

```
  # Copyright (c) 2002-2005 Rene Rivera.
  # Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0.
  # (See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)

  # The following #// line will be used by the regression test table generation
  # program as the column heading for HTML tables. Must not include version number.
  #//<a href="http://gcc.gnu.org/">GNU<br>GCC</a>

  # compute directories for invoking GCC
  #
  # The gcc toolset can be user-configured using the following
  # variables:
  #
  # GCC_ROOT_DIRECTORY
  #       The directory in which GCC was installed. Defaults to
  #       unset. Usually, there is no need to set this variable at
  #       all. However, if G++ is not in the path it is usually
  #       sufficient to configure this one variable. More fine-grained
  #       configuration is available by setting the following:
  #
  # GCC_BIN_DIRECTORY
  #       the directory prefix used to find the gcc executables. Defaults to
  #       $(GCC_ROOT_DIRECTORY)/bin/, or "" if GCC_ROOT_DIRECTORY is
  #       not set.
  #
  # GCC_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY
  #       the directory in which to find system includes. Defaults to
  #       empty.
  #
  # GCC_STDLIB_DIRECTORY
  #       the directory in which to find the standard library
  #       objects associated with this build of gcc. Defaults to
  #       $(GCC_ROOT_DIRECTORY)/lib.
  #
  # GXX
  #       The name by which g++ is invoked. You can also use this in
  #       lieu of setting the <cxxflags> property to force options such
  #       as "-V3.0.4" into the g++ command line: "-sGXX=g++ -V3.0.4".
  #
  # GCC
  #       Similar to GXX, the name by which gcc is invoked for "C"
  #       language targets.

  # singleton variables...
  set-as-singleton GCC_ROOT_DIRECTORY GCC_BIN_DIRECTORY GCC_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY GCC_STDLIB_DIRECTORY ;

  flags gcc GCC_BIN_DIRECTORY : $(GCC_BIN_DIRECTORY) ;
  flags gcc GCC_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY : $(GCC_INCLUDE_DIRECTORY) ;
  flags gcc GCC_STDLIB_DIRECTORY : $(GCC_STDLIB_DIRECTORY) ;

  GCC_BIN_DIRECTORY ?= $(GCC_ROOT_DIRECTORY)$(SLASH)bin ;
  GCC_BIN_DIRECTORY ?= "" ; # Don't clobber tool names if GCC_ROOT_DIRECTORY not set
  GCC_STDLIB_DIRECTORY ?= $(GCC_ROOT_DIRECTORY)$(SLASH)lib ;

  # Make sure this gets set "on" the target
  flags gcc GCC_BIN_DIR : $(GCC_BIN_DIRECTORY) ;

  flags gcc LINKFLAGS <runtime-link>static : -static ;
  flags gcc CFLAGS <debug-symbols>on : -g ;
  flags gcc LINKFLAGS <debug-symbols>on : -g ;
  flags gcc CFLAGS <optimization>off : -O0 ;
  flags gcc CFLAGS <optimization>speed : -O3 ;
```

In this part I can modify the default gcc/g++ to my own using the variables which are defined in the comment section. However I don't know How to do that. For example, I write

```
 GCC_BIN_DIRECTORY=/opt/gcc-4.1.2/installed
```

But that gives me this error:

```
 rule GCC_ROOT_DIRECTORY=/opt/gcc-4.1.2/installed unknown in module
```

So how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is script `bjam`, or `b2`, take a look here: http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/reference/tools.html#bbv2.reference.tools.compiler.gcc

and try:

```
./b2 root /usr/local/mygcc
```

should be working with provided compiler